# Portable to use make-instance to make conditions?

Tags: error-handling, common-lisp, clos

In Common Lisp, is it portable to use `make-instance` instead of `make-condition` to make condition objects?

For example:

```
(define-condition foo (condition)
  ())

(make-condition 'foo)
(make-instance 'foo)
```

Does this have something to do with how conditions are placed in the CLOS class hierarchy? `(subtypep 'condition 'standard-class)` returns false in SBCL and CLISP. However, `make-instance` can make conditions in both implementations. Is this guaranteed by the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is explicitly not portable to do that.  From the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/e_cnd.htm):

> Conforming code must observe the following restrictions related to conditions:
>
> - `define-condition`, not `defclass`, must be used to define new condition types.
> - `make-condition`, not `make-instance`, must be used to create condition objects explicitly.
> - The `:report` option of `define-condition`, not `defmethod` for `print-object`, must be used to define a condition reporter.
> - `slot-value`, `slot-boundp`, `slot-makunbound`, and `with-slots` must not be used on condition objects. Instead, the appropriate accessor functions (defined by `define-condition`) should be used

Answer (score 4):

It is not portable, according to the 4th footnote in Practical Common Lisp chapter 19:

*"In some Common Lisp implementations, conditions are defined as subclasses of STANDARD-OBJECT, in which case SLOT-VALUE, MAKE-INSTANCE, and INITIALIZE-INSTANCE will work, but it's not portable to rely on it."*

Link to the particular page:

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the condition system in a certain implementation is using CLOS and supporting CLOS operations not by

```
(subtypep 'condition 'standard-class)
```

but maybe by using something like:

```
(subtypep (class-of (find-class 'condition)) 'standard-class)
```

The Common Lisp standard does not require implementations to use CLOS to implement *conditions*. Thus the condition system in the standard is defined without support for CLOS: no support for `make-instance` required, no support for making subclasses via `defclass` required, ... Thus one can also not count on other features of CLOS being used.

That's one of the *warts* of the Common Lisp standard from 1994.